# PHP Returning Wonky HTML

Tags: php, html, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I have spent way too much time trying to clean this up.

I am simply attempting to return some HTML from a shortcode, into a shortcode block within the content editor.

```
$next_friday = new DateTime();
$next_friday->modify('next friday');
$final_date = $next_friday->format('l, F j, Y');
    
$response_formatted = "<h3 class='has-text-align-left'>$final_date</h3>";
$response_formatted .= "<p>Pre-sale for <u>Next Friday</u> Will Start on Tuesday at 5pm</p>";

return $response_formatted;
```

Pretty straightforward ... but the end results is this HTML on the front end:

```
<h3 class="has-text-align-left">Friday, October 15, 2021</h3>
<p>
    "Pre-sale for "
     <u>Next Friday</u>
    " Will Start on Tuesday at 5pm"
</p>
```

What is going on with this shortcode block? I just need it to render normally, like:

```
<h3 class="has-text-align-left">Friday, October 15, 2021</h3>
<p>Pre-sale for <u>Next Friday</u> Will Start on Tuesday at 5pm</p>
```

Comment: I'd say your editor is applying some formatting to the HTML. The question is, does it matter? Does it display correctly on the final page?

Comment: You got `$reponse_formatted` and `$response_formatted` -- not the same.

Comment: @cottton that's just a typo in here. it wouldn't return if that were the live code. it's fixed.

Comment: The "Front end HTML" is that from "View Source" or "Inspect Element" there are important differences between the two. The first is raw from the server, the second is as interpreted by the browser.

Comment: Right click page, View Source, that's how it actually renders.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson yes, exactly. and what i showed above is how it's actually rendering.

Comment: @JonP I realize that. That's why I said "HTML" ... so the actual code rendered is what I posted above.

Comment: @dcolumbus It really isn't. That's just what your dev inspector is interpreting and outputting in developer console. If you won't click View Source then create a new GET request in Postman to the URL you are testing and view that. There's nothing in PHP that adds anything like what you're showing but that is exactly how Chrome or Edge would show it in dev tools.